# Is there a way to reduce the height of an element with margins or something?

Tags: html, css, height, margin

Since I want to have a bar with fixed height and a map that ocupies the rest of the page this would be great.

I have tried like so :

```
#header{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:30pt;
 background-color:#ff0066;
 z-index:2;
}

 //element to reduce
#map{
 position:absolute;
 height: 100%;   
 width: 100%;
 background-color:blue;
 margin-top:30pt;
 margin-bottom:-30pt;
}
```

If have created this fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/bmPpq/

P.S. I have actively searched the web for a solution to this with no success (except for using JS, but that sucks..)

Bascicly this is what I want:

```
 #map{
 height: 100% - 30pt;   
}
```

Comment: which element's height do you want to reduce ?

Comment: You want it to look like http://jsfiddle.net/bmPpq/8/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use min-height on the map for that.
This should work:

```
#map{
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30;
  left: 0;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 #header{
     position:relative;
    ...


    #map{
     position:relative;
      ....
```